# .on() not applying to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery

So I'm kind of baffled by this problem.  I'm duplicating this select when they use it.  The goal is to be able more players to a team.  If they add one, it creates another select.  If they add a second player then a third select is created.

Currently, it's only duplicating whenever the first select is changed.  Shouldn't `.on()` apply to all elements created dynamically after the javascript is parsed and bound?  How do I make it so it's only applying to the most recently added `select`?   Thanks in advance for your time!

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    another = $('#addplayers');
    $('.addplayer').on('change', function(){
        another.clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo($(this).closest('.form-horizontal'));
        $(this).removeClass('addplayer');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="addplayers">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add Player</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="addplayer" team="<%=@team.id%>">
                                <%@players.each do |player|%>
                                    <option value="<%=player.id%>"><%=player.name%></option>
                                <%end%>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply correct syntax for **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** using:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.addplayer', function(){
```

instead of:

```
$('.addplayer').on('change', function(){
```

Comment: My understanding was that this method was deprecated with the newer versions of jquery.  Trying it

Comment: `.on()` is not deprecated, you just made a mistake in applying it in the correct way.

Comment: I mean, using `$(document.body).on('change', '.addplayer', function(){` this method of event delegation.

Comment: @Aarmora It's not deprecated at all.

Comment: @dystroy Searching for docs now. It's definitely working on my page as is suggested by Felix so I'm just trying to find why I thought that and started doing my code like `.live()` used to be done.